# cabal install --enable-test cause "cannot satisfy -package-id"

Tags: haskell, cabal

I tried to make own my haskell package which is called `Ringo` with using HUnit.
And when I run `cabal install --enable-test` I run into these error.

```
Linking dist/dist-sandbox-aa80c02c/build/ringo/ringo ...
Preprocessing test suite 'tests' for Ringo-0.1.0.0...
<command line>: cannot satisfy -package-id Ringo-0.1.0.0-inplace
(use -v for more information)
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
Ringo-0.1.0.0 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

This is Ringo.cabal

```
Test-Suite tests
  type:                exitcode-stdio-1.0
  main-is:             Tests.hs
  hs-source-dirs:      tests
  build-depends:       base, Ringo, transformers, test-framework, test-framework-hunit, HUnit
  default-language:    Haskell2010
```

And `cabal check` alert nothing.